# Retrieve last message for each conversation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a chat-like system on my website. I would like to make a list of conversation displaying the last message sent or received with each user I discussed with. Same as you can see on whatsapp or messenger or SMS applications.

My Message model looks like this for now:

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages_sent')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages_received')
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I tried few things, the closest I achieved was this:

```py
latest_messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).order_by('sender', 'receiver', '-date').distinct('sender', 'receiver')
```

The problem is, it returns the last message sent AND the last message received for each user, when I want the last of these 2.

Here is an example, let say I have 4 users sending messages my message table looks like this:

[image]

If I'm the user with the id 1 the request should return me 2 message instance.

The one with id 330 (last message exchanged with user_id 7) and the one with id 321 ( last message exchanged with user_id 2)

If I'm user_id 7 I will get message_id 330 and 327 and if I'm user 2 I will get message_id 327 and 321.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
latest_messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).order_by('-date','sender', 'receiver').distinct('sender', 'receiver').first()
```

This will first order by date descending, and then by sender, reciever. then select the latest message using `first()`.

Or if it doesn't work somehow then you can skip the sender and reciever altogether in the `order by` and only use date by descending to get the latest message, be it of the sender or reciever:

```
latest_messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).order_by('-date').distinct('sender', 'receiver').first()
```

Comment: @Tartempion34 can you kindly show the response you are getting on your current query?

Comment: On the both I got an error: "SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions", which make sense but the .first() anyway will return only one message which is not what I expect.

I edited my message above to reflect my needs ;)